# How to create jar for the java files created by JAXB?

Tags: java, maven, jar, jaxb

In my project some java files are created by JAXB and then Maven creates a jar file including these java files created by JAXB. Now, i need these java files(created by JAXB) to be in another jar file that we will import later to be used in our project.
Will really appreciate kind help?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to depend on jaxb objects + whatever you already have in your projet, i'm afraid the only clean solution would be to create another (sub)project, which contain only those jaxb generated files and include it.